# Rails not choosing the right layout for javascript requests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, mootools

I have two different layouts in my app, one for javascript (AJAX) requests and one for regular requests.

```
# application.html.haml for non-js requests (abbreviated)
!!!
%html
  %head
  %body
    = yield

# and application.js.coffee for js requests
App.modal """<%= yield %>""" # creates a javascript modal
```

Any link with `:remote => true` should in theory use the javascript layout.  This DOES work on certain occasions, but does not work on others.

It works for this link:

```
%li= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, remote: true

# log output:
Started GET "/users/sign_in?&authenticity_token=KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-27 03:29:41 -0500
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI="}
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/application (6.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 167ms (Views: 165.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

# output in the javascript console:
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in?&authenticity_token=KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI=".
```

But does not work for this one:

```
%li= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path, remote: true

# log output:
Started GET "/users/edit?&authenticity_token=KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-27 03:31:24 -0500
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  MobilePhone Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "mobile_phones".* FROM "mobile_phones" WHERE "mobile_phones"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (6.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 157ms (Views: 154.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

# output in the javascript console:
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/users/edit?&authenticity_token=KwyFmzGgR7Rdx3dudJDvw8b5rngvVDrwfTpYLPIPjEI=".
```

After some simple debugging, I realized that the second request is hitting `application.html.haml` (wrong!), while the first one is hitting `application.js.coffee` (correct!). Both are being processed successfully by ajax.

I am a bit stumped here. I am hoping that I am making a simple mistake that somebody will be able to point out!

Thanks!

P.S. I am running rails 3.2.1 (and previously tried on 3.1.3 with same issue)

EDIT: Not sure if it makes a difference, but I am using the mootools-rails driver: https://github.com/kevinvaldek/mootools-ujs/blob/master/Source/rails.js. The accepts header is being set properly to "text/javascript".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do to get this to work: (and has nothing to do with the javascript library)

```
# whatever_controller.rb
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js   # renders index.html.haml inside application.js.haml layout
    format.html # renders index.html.haml inside application.html.haml layout
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could just rename the template for the action to `index.js.haml` instead of `index.html.haml`, which would work for ajax requests without using `respond_to`. However, that would mean that search engines and browsers without javascript enabled would not be able to access the page.

Another method that would also work is to use `respond_with`:

```
# application_controller.rb
respond_to :html, :js

# whatever_controller.rb
def index
  respond_with # will render the appropriate layout
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, I tried with a new `rails 3.2.7` from scratch and as I used **application.haml** instead of **application.html.erb**, remote links was not working. I tried this work around:

1. Convert **application.haml** to a partial, rename **application.haml** to **_application.haml**
2. In **application.html.erb** just one line:

   ```
   <%= render 'application' %>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As for the layout you should specify it explicitly on the controller. Maybe you can change the name application.js.coffee to another name and add layout 'new_name' on the top of the controller.

Comment: Thanks, I can try that, but shouldn't rails automatically choose the appropriate layout based upon the request header?  The request header is currently set to "text/javascript" (using the mootools rails driver), yet it is using the wrong layout. Additionally I added respond_to :js at the top of the controller, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Also, I would like application.html.haml to be the layout as a fallback if a user doesn't have javascript enabled, or for search engines

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery UJS then try adding a

```
 data-type="script"
```

attribute to your link tag. This will set the dataType of the jQuery request which in turn sets the Accepts: header of your http request. Rails usest that to guess the appropriate response type for your request.

See this blog post for some background information: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/

Comment: Good point, but I'm actually using the Mootools UJS driver (https://github.com/kevinvaldek/mootools-ujs/blob/master/Source/rails.js)